# Build trend chart in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, react-native

How do I build this kind of chart which only show trend line b/w dates.
I've also using `Victory Native` but this kind of chart is not possible.

[PLEASE SEE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVGOD.png)

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see this `https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/`
I think You can build this by using this

Comment: This can not possible with library. It can be Only possible to build custom by using `react-native-svg` and `D3`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).